# visualizing the definition of homemorphism

Tags: general-topology

A friend of mine asked me to explain why a line segment say $L$ and the arc say $A$ which is created from that line segment are Homeomorphic. He believes in the physical concept that he can continuously deform  one into another but he can not relate this incident with the definition of Homeomorphism i.e  there exist continuous bijection $f:L\to A$ with $f^{-1}$ continuous.
Could anyone tell me how to convince him mathematicaly as well as what he believe physically?

Comment: Maybe you can see $A$ as the graph of a continuous function $f$. Then $f$ is your homeomorphism, ant its inverse is the $x$-projection.

Answer (score 1):

To "continuously deform one into another" basically means that at every step of the "deformation" the two spaces locally have the same shape. This notion of local similarity is what is encoded in a bicontinuous bijection $f:L\to A$. That is, the notion of proximity (which point is near which) is preserved when going from $L$ to $A$ and back.

---

Coming to your example, as @Seirios correctly suggests, you could embed $A$ in $\Bbb A^2$ in such a way that the projection on one of the coordinate axes gives a homeomorphism.